# topic distristribution in gensim ldamodel trained with countvectorizer

Tags: python-3.x, gensim, topic-modeling, countvectorizer

I have an assignment that's something like this:

```
import gensim
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

newsgroup_data = ["Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications",
             "A survey of user opinion of computer system response time",
              "The EPS user interface management system",
              "System and human system engineering testing of EPS",
              "Relation of user perceived response time to error measurement",
              "The generation of random binary unordered trees",
              "The intersection graph of paths in trees",
              "Graph minors IV Widths of trees and well quasi ordering",
              "Graph minors A survey"]

vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english', 
                       token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w\\w+\\b')
X = vect.fit_transform(newsgroup_data)
corpus = gensim.matutils.Sparse2Corpus(X, documents_columns=False)
id_map = dict((v, k) for k, v in vect.vocabulary_.items())
```

My task is to estimate LDA model parameters on the corpus, find a list of the 10 topics and the most significant 10 words in each topic, which I do as such:

```
top10 = ldamodel.print_topics(num_topics=10, num_words=10)
ldamodel = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus, 
              id2word=id_map, num_topics=10, minimum_probability=0)
```

Which passes the autograder fine.  The next task is to find the topic distribution of a new doc which I attempt to do as follows:

```
new_doc = ["\n\nIt's my understanding that the freezing will start to occur because \
of the\ngrowing distance of Pluto and Charon from the Sun, due to it's\nelliptical orbit. \
It is not due to shadowing effects. \n\n\nPluto can shadow Charon, and vice-versa.\n\nGeorge \
Krumins\n-- "]
newX = vect.transform(new_doc)
newC = gensim.matutils.Sparse2Corpus(newX, documents_columns=False)
print(ldamodel.get_document_topics(newC))
```

This however simply returns

`gensim.interfaces.TransformedCorpus`

I also see from the docs the statement: "You can then infer topic distributions on new, unseen documents, with >>> doc_lda = lda[doc_bow]" but have no success here either.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Continued digging into this, specifically for the interface gensim.interfaces.TransformedCorpus.  As I understand it, the interface points to the topic/distribution I've asked for but I need to iterated through it to see the values.

```
topic_dist = ldamodel.get_document_topics(newC)
td=[]
for topic in topic_dis:
   td.append(topic)
td = td[0]
```

does the trick.  Could also use

```
topic_dist = ldamodel[newC]
```